# Broken css of "Select your next badge" box

Tags: bug, design, badges

The design of the box below is broken in current Firefox.

This makes the filtering line to divide into two and the content of the window overflows. Not sure if this is recent change or it was here earlier.

[image: sec.se]

When compared to the other sites, the bounding box of the filter links (marked in the images) have different box model than on the other SE sites, for example screenshot from Unix.

[image: unix.se]

Comment: @TildalWave Dunno. It is not a problem on other sites. But if you think, feel free to flag/close/move/vote.

Comment: @Jakuje Can you confirm that this issue is still happening? I've checked it in Firefox locally and I cannot repo the issue.

Comment: @Hynes Yes. I still see it all the same (both main site and meta). Might note that I am using Linux, but it should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I don't know what has changed, but it looks good now.

The bounding box looks still the same, so it might have been a bug in Firefox. Currently using Firefox 45.0.1, which works fine.